# Istio allow incoming traffic to a service only from a particular namespace

Tags: istio

We want Istio to allow incoming traffic to a service only from a particular namespace. How can we do this with Istio? We are runnning Istio 1.1.3 version.

Update:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-app-ingress
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
  ingress:
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          istio: ingress
```

This did not work I am able to access the service from other namespaces as well. Next i tried:

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRole
metadata:
  name: external-api-caller
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  rules:
  - services: ["testapp"]
    methods: ["*"]
    constraints:
    - key: "destination.labels[version]"
      values: ["v1", "v2"]
---
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-api-caller
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  subjects:
  - properties:
      source.namespace: "default"
  roleRef:
    kind: ServiceRole
    name: "external-api-caller"
```

I am able to access the service from all the namespaces. Where i expected it should be allowed only from "default" namespace

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible for particular namespace, but it will work on labels.

You can create a network policy in [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/), this is nicely explained on [Traffic Routing in Kubernetes via Istio and Envoy Proxy](https://www.appliedis.com/traffic-routing-in-kubernetes-via-istio-and-envoy-proxy/).

```
...
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          zone: trusted
...
```

In the example only pods with label `zone: trusted` will be allowed to make incoming connection to the pod.

You can read about [Using Network Policy with Istio](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-using-network-policy/).

I would also recommend reading [Security Concepts in Istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/) as well as [Denials and White/Black Listing](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/).

Hope this helps You.

Comment: Thanks @Crou I had looked at these options:

Answer (score 0):

**Using k8s Network Policy**: Yes it is possible. The example that is posted in the question is not allowing from a different namespace. In the Ingress rule you have to use namespace selector which will be used to specify the namespace from which you want to allow the traffic. In the example below, namespace with label 'ns-group: prod-ns' will be allowed to access the pod with label 'app: testapp' on port 80 and protocol TCP

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-app-ingress
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
  ingress:
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns-group: prod-ns
```

**Using Istio White Listing Policy**: You can go through [white listing policy examples](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/) and [attribute vocabulary](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/)

Below is the example,

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: whitelist-namespace
spec:
  compiledAdapter: listchecker
  params:
    overrides: ["prod-ns"]
    blacklist: false
---

apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: source-ns-instance
spec:
  compiledTemplate: listentry
  params:
    value: source.namespace
---

apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: rule-policy-1
spec:
  match: destination.labels["app"] == "testapp" && destination.namespace == "test-ns"
  actions:
  - handler: whitelist-namespace
    instances: [ source-ns-instance ]
```